# Can't Explain C++ Performance

Tags: c++, performance

If you have a variable, A, that never changes and always equals zero, a function F, a function G, and a function H, and call the following code on a modern Intel desktop processor with -O3 optimization on a modern version of GCC:

```
for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; i++)
{
if(A != 0) F();
else G();
}
```

It takes 2 seconds to execute. Note that F is never, ever called because A is always 0. Alternatively,

```
for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; i++)
{
if(A != 0) H();
else G();
}
```

only takes 1 second to execute. Again, A is always 0 and H is never called. Lastly,

```
for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; i++)
{
G();
}
```

only takes 0.5 seconds to execute.

Given the conditional statement in the first two examples, why does it matter what the content of F and H are? Since they are never called, why does it make a difference what they do? And given that Intel processors have sophisticated branch prediction, shouldn't the processor figure out that G() is always called and never even waste time on the conditional statement? I understand that the conditional instruction should waste some time but I don't get why it wastes so much time.

Comment: Please provide a complete, simple, compilable, standalone example that demonstrates the relative performance.  (Also, note that a benchmark that runs in a few seconds or less is very, very likely to have very noisy results, and note that the best way to figure out the cause of the performance difference is often to look at the generated assembly.)

Comment: Why would a compare statement take zero time? If GCC does not have enough info to optimize it out, there go your CPU cycles.

Comment: Are any of F, G, or H declared `inline`? Is A declared `const`? Do these three code fragments appear in a single `main`? Regarding the latter: caching may explain some of the performance differences; try reordering the three code blocks.

Comment: Look at the intermediate "ASM" *output* (`-S`) to see what the compiler things should go on as well.

Comment: I'm not expecting GCC to fix this for me because the conditional always equaling zero isn't evident in the code. I'm expecting the Intel processor with its fancy branch prediction technologies to notice that the branch in the loop always turns out a certain way and stop taking a speculative path into F/H, which is whats burning so much execution time.

Comment: @JeremyFowers That desire is not *clearly* evident in the title, tags, or body of the original post... it might make more sense to try and draw more focus to it to get more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that compiler understands that `A` is a constant, it should turn this code:

```
for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; i++)
{
    if(A != 0) F();
    else G();
}
```

into this:

```
if(A != 0)
    for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; ++i)
        F();
else
    for(i = 0; i < a_big_number; ++i)
        G();
```

Or totally optimize out the `F()` function call if a constant appears to be a compile-time constant.

If that is not happening (i.e. there are possible side effects or something else - compiler does not guarantee you how and what it optimizes), the loop will encounter a performance hit that comes from a branch mis-prediction. The CPU should lock on the loop and remember the branch if A is not changing and a called function is small enough, so it won't repeat the same mistake over and over. On the other hand, the loop might get unrolled, and that could hurt a lot since it cannot be parallelized and will only blow the code size and a number of things CPU have to keep track of.

How you measure the execution time though is a mystery for me, as well as what that function that you call in a loop is doing. You could be measuring process execution swap-outs, for example. So it is impossible to tell you what is going on unless you provide a complete working example with a detailed explanation of your measurement method.

At any rate, I bet that your time measurement is incorrect, or you do something bad in the code that you are not showing, or all of the above.

Comment: +1 for your point on actually measuring time. It's unfortunately easy to measure time in a way that doesn't actually measure what you want. And even more unfortunately, people who haven't done this much tend to get thoroughly convinced that their method of measuring time *can't* be the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know compilers cannot determine if a branch will not execute. The best that a compiler can do is predict which branch is more likely.

Comment: Compilers cannot, but CPU has a branch prediction mechanism that works very well. Not to mention that compilers actually do have profile-based optimizations and hints for branch predictions to re-arrange generated code.